# delete email field google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I am simply trying to *use google apps script code to create a new contact, and label the email field as "Work" because it defaults to "Home"* when it is created. (I am trying to do this using a form, but for test purposes, it's a simple Run trigger)

I have tried so many different iterations that there are too many to list here. But my latest workaround (as all things are with google) is to let the thing create the default "Home" email field when the contact is created, then add a "Work" field email, and then delete the "Home" - but the `deleteEmailField` which is listed in the google documentation never works.

Here is the latest I've put together:

```
function testAddcontact() {
var firstName= "Contact"
var lastName= "Test2"
var email= "testy@test.com"
var newcontact = ContactsApp.createContact( firstName, lastName , email );
newcontact.addEmail("Work", email);
newcontact.deleteEmailField("Home");
}
```

I have tried so many variations that I can't provide all the code I've worked on here, but I have inserted above my latest attempt.

Thoughts anyone on how to create a contact and label that email address "Work" instead of the default "Home"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet should work:

```
function testAddcontact() {
  var firstName= "Contact"
  var lastName= "Test2"
  var email= "testy@test.com"
  var newcontact = ContactsApp.createContact( firstName, lastName , email );
  newcontact.addEmail(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL, email);
  var emailArr = newcontact.getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL);
  emailArr[0].deleteEmailField();
}
```

just remember that:

standard labels are Field objects

deleteEmailField is a EmailField method

Comment: thanks, I tried that and got this back: ReferenceError: "getEmails" is not defined.

Comment: :-) thanks again - now I get this error: Service error: ContactsApp: Mismatch: etags = [&quot;Rns8eTVSLit7I2A9WhNSFU8CRQY.&quot;], version = [1351528227465001]. it does actually create the contact and 2 email fields - but keeps getting hung on that delete method. is there an easier way for me to hardwire in the "work" label upon creation of the contact? maybe take delete out of it altogether? (FYI - did google search for error, and of course nothing came up)

Comment: woo hoo - took some of your suggestion and just went ahead and changed the label to Work `function testAddcontact2() {
  var firstName= "Contact"
  var lastName= "Test2"
  var email= "testy@test.com"
  var newcontact = ContactsApp.createContact( firstName, lastName , email );
  var emailArr = newcontact.getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL);
  emailArr[0].setLabel("Work");
}` but I guess we'll never know why the delete method never worked

Comment: i've been trying some other stuff like adding a custom field - it works, but is seems google only allows one edit per - for example, I couldn't set label of the email field and then create the custom field, it only let's me do one or the other - any experience with that?

Comment: Changing the label of the existing home-email is a slick idea. you should however use the ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL object instead of the "Work" string.

Comment: Contacts reside in Google's distributed storage. If you create a new contact, the object gets apreliminary status until the storage cloud returns the final id. You will need to set up a try-catch block to sleep for a sec and retry the operation if needed. The label change will be done very often even if the "etags" error shows up. If the error shows up, it a message that the operatinon is not confirmed.

Comment: thx, yeah found something late yesterday about that - wound up inserting the utilities sleep in the function.